# How can I test TCP/IP AT-Commands with server?

Tags: gsm, port, tcp-ip, server

I'm currently using [SIM868](http://simcom.ee/documents/?dir=SIM868) to make a GPS tracker, I wanted to know how  to test tcp/ip protocol with a server. I do not have a server but got a website and a wifi connection(DIR-600M Router) , Is there any way I can use a virtual port listener or something to test the communication?

Comment: In principle yes, but only in one direction. You'll have to get the SIM868 to make a connection to your web site on port 80 and send it a GET request, and get your web site to respond with a simple page.

Comment: can i use port forwarding in my router to do it?

Comment: A web site's job is to service HTTP requests from clients, which is surely how you want your tracker to work anyway. Making it do the opposite is a massive amount of work and way off-topic for this site.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is unclear IMHO (perhaps translation / terminology issues?) e.g. you say that you don't have a *server*, but you do have a *website*. When a computer is servicing incoming HTTP requests (i.e. a website) that computer *is* a server (even if it is a tiny RPi etc.) as the incoming requests coming from HTTP *clients* like the SIM868 (client/server model). So your statements seem to contradict each other, making it unclear :-( Since this seems to be a networking question (the SIM868 is just a TCP/IP client) perhaps this should be migrated to Network Engineering stack?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your best bet would be to get a virtual private server somewhere. But in the interim, you can probably test it by attempting an HTTP request on some other publicly accessible website.

Comment: Can you give me an example for 'publicly available website.'? and I'm using TCP from the GSM module.

Comment: Google? Really, any website that you can load up in your browser should work.

Comment: Maybe 'accessible' would be a better word

Comment: then it should work with the website that I owns know? and what is the port number I should be using?

Comment: Sure, if you have a publicly accessible website, then it should work.  HTTP uses port 80.

Comment: Hi, I tried this to my website's ip and I'm able to connect and send data but the 'SEND OK' reply that has to be received for the GSM after sending has been finished is not coming up.http://www.python-exemplary.com/download/sim800_series_tcpip_application_note_v1.00.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71526/discussion-between-arun-joe-and-alex-forencich).